# How to apply different background images to radio buttons where class and ID are already defined

Tags: input, radio-button, background-image

I am trying to define CSS for a radio button input which already has an ID (#3872720) and falls within a parent DIV with a class called `.catProdAttributeItem`

I am simply wanting to display a graphic with this ID using a background image. The code for the attributes that appear is already created by the Business Catalyst system so I cannot control it, all I can do is target the class names and ID names that the output code produces.

so I am trying to achieve:

```
text    radio  bg image:

white   o     image 1 here  
yello   o     image 2 here  
green   o     image 3 here  
black   o     image 4 here
```

BODY

```
<div class="catProductAttributeGroup">
<div class="catProdAttributeTitle">Colour</div>
<div class="catProdAttributeItem"> 
  <input id="3872720" name="578278" mandatory="1" type="radio">
  <span>White </span></div>
<div class="catProdAttributeItem">
  <input id="3872721" name="578278" mandatory="1" type="radio">
  <span>Yellow </span></div>
<div class="catProdAttributeItem">
  <input id="3872722" name="578278" mandatory="1" type="radio">
  <span>Green </span></div>
<div class="catProdAttributeItem">
  <input id="3872723" name="578278" mandatory="1" type="radio">
  <span>Black </span></div>
```

CSS

```
.catProdAttributeItem input{color:#fff; padding-left:30px;}  
#3872720 input {padding-left:20px; background-image:url(../images/shop-dot-white.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat;}  
#3872721 input {padding-left:20px; background-image:url(../images/shop-dot-yellow.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat;}  
#3872722 input {padding-left:20px; background-image:url(../images/shop-dot-green.jpg);  background-repeat:no-repeat;}  
#3872723 input {padding-left:20px;  background-image:url(../images/shop-dot-black.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat;}
```

The question is how do I target `class="catProdAttributeItem"` and input `id="3872721"`...?

Any help would be much appreciated!